# Trying to create a DataFrame from two lists and an array

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have two lists and an array that need to be transformed into a DataFrame. This is more or less what I have:

```
listA = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
listB = ['x', 'y', 'z']

array = [[10, 11, 12], [20, 21, 22], [30, 31, 32], [40, 41, 42]]
```

I want my DataFrame to be like this:

[image]

I've tried creating the DataFrame by inserting the lists into

```
pd.Dataframe()
```

and then specifying what the column's name should be. But no luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pd.MultiIndex.from_product`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) helps here; it will take the cartesian product of two lists given and give a MultiIndex with 2 levels populated as such:

```py
>>> pd.DataFrame(np.ravel(array),
                 index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([listA, listB]), 
                 columns=["value"])
     value
a x     10
  y     11
  z     12
b x     20
  y     21
  z     22
c x     30
  y     31
  z     32
d x     40
  y     41
  z     42
```

- values are the raveled (flattened) array
- index is the product of the two lists
- columns is the "value" which is the only one.

Comment: Thank you! But, is there a way to maintain each column as described in the picture? The whole idea is to access the "value" column by looking up a (listA, listB) location.

Comment: hi Diego, you can do that with, for example, `df.loc[("b", "z"), "value"]`: this will look up the value of the "value" column where listA is "b" and listB is "z". Therefore it gives 22. Is that what you meant? Currently, the listA and listB values are in the *index* as a MultiIndex with 2 levels. That allows us to reach values with `.loc` as shown above with a tuple in the row-selection part.

Answer (score 0):

```
out = pd.DataFrame(array, index=listA, columns=listB).stack()
```

out:

```
a  x    10
   y    11
   z    12
b  x    20
   y    21
   z    22
c  x    30
   y    31
   z    32
d  x    40
   y    41
   z    42
dtype: int64
```